# What does the "would have been" express in this sentence?

Tags: conditionals

> If so, the green algae **would have been** subjected to environmental pressures that resulted in adaptations that enhanced their potential to give rise to land-dwelling organisms.(From TPO 25 )

would haven

Answer (score 2):

it is just a more formal sounding way of saying "had been", had this thing have happened.

> If so, the green algae **had been** subjected to environmental
>   pressures that resulted in adaptations that enhanced their potential
>   to give rise to land-dwelling organisms.(From TPO 25 )